# Spring Boot Constructor Based Dependency Injection not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I've used Spring Boot to develop a REST Service. In one of the REST controllers I have a field based dependency injection that I like to change to a constructor based dependency injection. My setup of the dependency injections currently looks like this:

```
@RestController
public class ParameterDateController {

    private ParameterDateController() {
    }

    private ParameterDate parameterDate;

    private ParameterDateController(ParameterDate parameterDate) {
        this.parameterDate = parameterDate;
    }

    @Autowired
    private ParameterDateService parameterDateService;

// here are the metods of the endpoints
}
```

With this setup everything works fine. I would likt to change `ParameterDateService` to constructor based and I tried with this:

```
@RestController
public class ParameterDateController {

    private ParameterDateController() {
    }

    private ParameterDate parameterDate;

    private ParameterDateController(ParameterDate parameterDate) {
        this.parameterDate = parameterDate;
    }

    private ParameterDateService parameterDateService;

    private ParameterDateController(ParameterDateService parameterDateService) {
        this.parameterDateService = parameterDateService;
    }

// here are the metods of the endpoints
}
```

After the change to constructor based dependency injection I get a `NullPointerException` when I try to inject the dependency like this `parameterDateService.postParameterDate(parameterDate);`. I inject the same way when I have it setup as field based dependency injection and that gives no `NullPointerException`. The constructor based dependency injection for `ParameterDate` works as expected.

What is it I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You must add Autowired on the second constructor. Or remove the first one. You should also make it public: what's the point of a constructor you can't call without reflection? If you're happy with that, field injection is also fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have two dependencies wired via constructor - you have to declare them as constructor parameters, so here you have to declare:

```
public ParameterDateController(ParameterDate parameterDate, ParameterDateService parameterDateService) {
    this.parameterDate = parameterDate;
    this.parameterDateService = parameterDateService;
}
```

Here's [a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24363707/1126831) about constructor injection.