# test spring 5 reactive rest service

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, reactor

I'm using SpringBoot 2 and Spring 5 (RC1) to expose reactive REST services. but I can't manage to write unit test for those controllers.

Here is my controller

```
@Api
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;


    @RequestMapping(path = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Flux<MyModel> getPages(@RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) String id,
            @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name) throws Exception {

        return myService.getMyModels(id, name);
    }
}
```

myService is calling a database so I would like not to call the real one. (I don't wan't integration testing)

Edit :

I found a way that could match my need but I can't make it work :

```
@Before
    public void setup() {

        client = WebTestClient.bindToController(MyController.class).build();

    }
@Test
    public void getPages() throws Exception {

        client.get().uri("/").exchange().expectStatus().isOk();

    }
```

But I'm getting 404, seems it can't find my controller

Comment: Quick Google shot: http://memorynotfound.com/unit-test-spring-mvc-rest-service-junit-mockito/

Comment: Hi @jannis, thanks but it's neither a rest api test nor a reactive rest api test and I did of course start by googling this one

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the Flux part...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass actual controller instance to `bindToController` method.
As you want to test mock environment, you'll need to mock your dependencies, for example using [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org/).

```
public class MyControllerReactiveTest {

    private WebTestClient client;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        client = WebTestClient
                .bindToController(new MyController(new MyService()))
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void getPages() throws Exception {
        client.get()
                .uri("/")
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk();
    }

}
```

More test examples you can find [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/tree/master/spring-test/src/test/java/org/springframework/test/web/reactive/server/samples).

Also, I suggest switching to [constructor-based DI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24363707/1126831).